# Switch process using condition check rather than swap in a wordLadder

Tags: python

I mimic a bidirectional solution to wordLadder problem in leetcode
[Word Ladder - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/solution/)

> Given two words (*beginWord* and *endWord*), and a dictionary's word list, find the length of shortest transformation sequence from *beginWord* to *endWord*, such that:
>
> 1. Only one letter can be changed at a time.
> 2. Each transformed word must exist in the word list. Note that *beginWord* is *not* a transformed word.
>
> **Note:**
>
> - Return 0 if there is no such transformation sequence.
> - All words have the same length.
> - All words contain only lowercase alphabetic characters.
> - You may assume no duplicates in the word list.
> - You may assume *beginWord* and *endWord* are non-empty and are not the same.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> beginWord = "hit",
> endWord = "cog",
> wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]
>
> Output: 5
>
> Explanation: As one shortest transformation is "hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" -> "cog",
> return its length 5.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> beginWord = "hit"
> endWord = "cog"
> wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"]
>
> Output: 0
>
> Explanation: The endWord "cog" is not in wordList, therefore no possible transformation.
> ```

the solution

```
class Solution2(object):
    def ladderLength(self, beginWord, endWord, wordList):
        #base case
        if (endWord not in wordList) or (not endWord) or (not beginWord) or (not wordList):
            return 0
        size = len(beginWord)
        word_set = set(wordList)    
        forwards, backwards = {beginWord}, {endWord}
        visited = set()
        step = 0
        while forwards and backwards:
            step += 1 #treat the first word as step 1
            if len(forwards) > len(backwards): 
                forwards, backwards = backwards, forwards #switch process
            #logging.debug(f"step: {step}, forwards: {forwards}, backwords: {backwards}")

            neighbors= set()   
            for word in forwards:#visit words on this level
                if word in visited: continue

                for i in range(size):
                    for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                        next_word = word[:i] + c + word[i+1:]
                        if next_word in backwards: return step +  1 #terminating case
                        if next_word in word_set: neighbors.add(next_word)
                        #logging.debug(f"next_word{next_word}, step: {step}")
                visited.add(word) #add visited word as the final step 
            forwards = neighbors 
        #logging.debug(f"final: {step}")
        return 0
```

[image]

Reference to switch process

```
        if len(forwards) > len(backwards): 
            forwards, backwards = backwards, forwards #switch process
```

This solution is concise but not intuitive, I tried to change it to

```
if len(forwards) <= len(backward): current = forwards
else: current = backwards
neighbors = set()
for word in current:
 .......
```

Unfortunately, the final step `forwards = neighbors` cannot be handled properly.

How could solve the prolem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called [bidirectional search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) aglorithm. `forward` and `backward` in this solution is kind of `two-pointer` idea, always choose the larger set to do [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). it helps to find the path more quickly.

about the question you want to use `current` instead of switch `forward` and `backward`, I think it is impossible. The reason is, we use both `forward` and `backward` in the logic, so beyond `current` you should also provide a variable like `another`. but `current` and `another` is same as `forward` and `backward`, so your idea doesn't work.

in my opinion, I think this `two-pointer` version is elegant and concise enough, and I personally like it.

I figure out another way, use `current index` is close to your idea:

```
class Solution:
    def ladderLength(self, beginWord, endWord, wordList):
        #base case
        if (endWord not in wordList) or (not endWord) or (not beginWord) or (not wordList):
            return 0
        size = len(beginWord)
        word_set = set(wordList)    
        entries = [{beginWord}, {endWord}]
        visited = set()
        step = 0
        cur = 0
        while entries[cur] and entries[1-cur]:
            step += 1 #treat the first word as step 1
            if entries[1-cur] > entries[cur]: #switch process
                cur ^= 1

            neighbors= set()   
            for word in entries[cur]:#visit words on this level
                if word in visited: continue

                for i in range(size):
                    for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                        next_word = word[:i] + c + word[i+1:]
                        if next_word in entries[1-cur]: return step +  1 #terminating case
                        if next_word in word_set: neighbors.add(next_word)

                visited.add(word) #add visited word as the final step 
            entries[cur] = neighbors 
        return 0
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )